# Measure disk I/O of a running process (not one I start)

Tags: java, linux, io

I have a long-running Java server, and I'd like to measure its disk I/O activity when I tell it to perform a certain task. On Linux, is there a way to start monitoring disk I/O on a process (or a JVM, if that helps)  and then stop monitoring later, and get the total bytes read and written to disk during that time period?

Answer (score 4):

Installing and running iotop will allow you to see I/O information for individual processes: http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/

[image: iotop output]

Comment: Will it help in finding the disk I/O for a given time period?

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli with the -n and -d options, one can control the length of time and how many iterations.  So `iotop -n 1 -d 10` will run once and show the usage for 10 seconds.  The --batch and --time options may also help make the output a bit clearer in this case.